# Degrees of freedom for a $\chi^2$ with non-linear polynomial model

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonlinear-regression, fitting, degrees-of-freedom, nonlinear

I have a $\chi^2$ below for some model function $F$: $$ \chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{i=M} \frac{\left(y_{i}-F\left(x_i;\vec{a}\right)\right)^2}{\left(\Delta y_{i}\right)^2} $$  I know that non-linear model should be used incredibly cautiously with $\chi^2$ statistics because a simple non-linear function like a sine wave $A\sin(B\theta+C)$ can fit an unlimited number of points despite only having 3 free parameters. Keeping that in mind, are there reasonable classes of functions where I can still use non-linear models?   The specific example I am imagining is where $$F = (\sum_{i=0}^{N}a_i x^i)^2$$Clearly if this function was not squared, it would be linear in the parameters and I would have $d.o.f. = M-N$. Surely the squared function cannot fit an unlimited number of points like the sine function, but I am wary to declare the $d.o.f.$ are the same, as it is non-linear in the parameters.

For clarity: $y$ is a set of observed values (measured data) with uncertainties $\Delta y$, $x$ is a variable which $F$ has functional dependence on, $\vec{a}$ is a vector of parameters the function depends on, and $N$ is the number of Parameters, and $M$ in the number of data points

Comment: There are notation conventions in statistics from which you seem to be deviating, and it makes your question hard to read. The big one is your use of $\sigma$ as something other than standard deviation. Yes, you say what it means, but that's such a standard notation that I have trouble getting past it.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've updated the notation

Comment: I don't understand why you are even using $\chi^2$ in this context.